# ¿Cómo ejecutar una consulta agrupando series continuas sobre una columna? ("Encontrando Islas", "Gap and Islands Problem")

Tags: sql-server, tsql

Considerando la siguiente tabla

```
create table detalle(
    id_fila int identity not null,
    id_grupo int not null,
    fecha date not null
);
```

poblada con los siguientes datos

```
insert into detalle(id_grupo,fecha)
values (1, '20191001') -- fecha en formato yyyymmdd
      ,(1, '20191005')
      ,(1, '20191006')
      ,(1, '20191007')
      ,(1, '20191101')
      ,(1, '20191102')
      ,(2, '20160523')
      ,(2, '20160524')
      ,(2, '20160524')
      ,(2, '20160624')
;
```

Es posible realizar, sin iterar, una consulta que detecte los periodos continuos sobre el valor de la columna `fecha` generando una tabla que agrupe por la columna `id_grupo` y genere dos columnas `inicio_periodo` y `final_periodo` en la que queden, respectivamente, los valores inicial y final de cada uno de los periodos continuos?

Para los datos con los que se pobla la tabla en este escenario el resultado esperado para la consulta que estoy intentando es :

[image: Resultado esperado para la consulta]

(NOTA:Para intepretar sin ambigüedad el resultado, aclaro que el formato de la fecha en la imagen de muestra es yyyy-MM-dd)

La versión del motor es SqlServer 2016

Muchas gracias por su atención, comentarios y respuestas

EDIT: El patron del problema se conoce como "Encontrando Islas" y en inglés como "Gaps and Islands Problem"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La solución que te planteo, es una adaptación de un problema que tiene múltiples maneras de acometer, que se conoce, como "encontrando islas".
Puede resultar algo compleja, por tanto te la voy a ir desmenuzando en trocitos y al final te pongo la respuesta completa.

Para que funcione, tu motor tiene que ser al menos 2012, porque utilizaremos la función de ventana LAG y esta aparece en 2012.

**Obtener grupos**

```
with c
     as (SELECT *
              , CASE
                     WHEN DATEDIFF(day, LAG(FECHA) OVER(PARTITION BY ID_GRUPO
                          ORDER BY fecha), fecha) = 1 THEN 0
                     ELSE 1
                END AS grp
                FROM DETALLE)
Select * from c
```

[image: Fase 1]

Ya tenemos en la columna grp, gracias a la diferencia en días de la fila en la que estamos con su registro anterior, si esta es igual a 1.

**Numerar grupos**

```
with c
     as (SELECT *,
                CASE
                     WHEN DATEDIFF(day, LAG(FECHA) OVER(PARTITION BY ID_GRUPO
                          ORDER BY fecha), fecha) = 1 THEN 0
                     ELSE 1
                END AS grp
                FROM DETALLE)
        ,
     c2
     As (select *
              , sum(grp) over(partition by id_grupo
                order by fecha rows between unbounded preceding and current row) as grupo
                from c)
Select * from c2
```

En el conjunto c2, lo que hacemos es darle una numeración a cada grupo diferenciada.

[image: Numerar]

De manera que ahora tenemos una columna grupo, que nos identifica a cada uno de ellos incrementalmente, por su id_grupo original.

**Obtener min y max de grupos**

```
with c
     as (SELECT *
              , CASE
                     WHEN DATEDIFF(day, LAG(FECHA) OVER(PARTITION BY ID_GRUPO
                          ORDER BY fecha), fecha) = 1 THEN 0
                     ELSE 1
                END AS grp
                FROM DETALLE),
     c2
     As (select *
              , sum(grp) over(partition by id_grupo
                order by fecha rows between unbounded preceding and current row) as grupo
                from c),
     c3
     as (select min(fecha) as fechaInicio
              , max(fecha) as fechafin
              , grupo
              , id_grupo
                from c2
                group by grupo
                       , id_grupo)
     select *
            from c3;
```

[image: min y max]

Ahora para cada grupo anterior, obtenemos las fechas minima y máxima.

**Eliminar coincidencias y dar salida**

Nos resta eliminar los registros que están en un grupo y en el siguiente, y dar la salida

```
with c
     as (SELECT *
              , CASE
                     WHEN DATEDIFF(day, LAG(FECHA) OVER(PARTITION BY ID_GRUPO
                          ORDER BY fecha), fecha) = 1 THEN 0
                     ELSE 1
                END AS grp
                FROM DETALLE),
     c2
     As (select *
              , sum(grp) over(partition by id_grupo
                order by fecha rows between unbounded preceding and current row) as grupo
                from c),
     c3
     as (select min(fecha) as fechaInicio
              , max(fecha) as fechafin
              , grupo
              , id_grupo
                from c2
                group by grupo
                       , id_grupo),
     c4
     as (select c3.id_grupo
              , c3.fechaInicio
              , c3.fechafin
              , CASE
                     WHEN DATEDIFF(day, LAG(fechafin) OVER(PARTITION BY ID_GRUPO
                          ORDER BY fechainicio), fechafin) = 0 THEN 1
                     ELSE 0
                END AS grp
                from c3
                group by c3.id_grupo
                       , c3.fechaInicio
                       , c3.fechafin)
 select c4.id_grupo
      , FORMAT(c4.fechaInicio,'yyyy-MM-dd', 'en-US') AS FechaInicio
      , FORMAT(c4.fechafin,'yyyy-MM-dd', 'en-US') AS FechaFin
        from c4
        where grp = 0;
```

[image: Salida final]

En el conjunto c3 marcamos, los registros donde no hay diferencia entre el grupo y su antecesor, y en la salida formateamos las fechas.

Existen muchas otras maneras de hacer esto. Puedes buscar por la web e implementar cualquiera de sus variantes.

También puedes cambiar format por Convert al formato ISO 8601, que es posible que mejore la performance de la misma. Pero la ventaja de esta función, es que lo puedes adecuar a tú antojo.

[Convert](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

[gaps and islands](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/9130/sql-server-window-functions-gaps-and-islands-problem/)

Comment: Exactamente lo que necesitaba Javi. Ignoraba que el problema ya tuviese un nombre y tal vez por no buscarlo con las palabras correctas no hallaba la solución. Tienes razon respecto al motor. El tema final del formato lo colocaba mas para que no hubiera ambiguedades al momento de quien interpretaba la información deseada como salida. Editaré la pregunta para corregir lo del motor e incluir el nombre del problema para que la pregunta pueda ser direccionada por las busquedas. Muchas Gracias

Comment: Javi para algunos escenarios en los que, para un mismo valor de `id_grupo` el dato de la fecha se repite mas de dos veces, parece que el predicado del case donde se calcula la primera columna `grp` no se comporta muy bien con `=1`; someto a tu revisión si para estos escenarios funcionaría mejor el predicado ' in (0,1)'. Gracias

Comment: No creo eso del predicado, Funcionaría mucho mejor con un Select disctinct *,.... from detalle. Ya que al final buscamos rangos, y no filas. Y eso nos permitiría la eliminación del grp de c4.

Comment: Bien. Muchas gracias